# Compare values between dataframes and return corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two data frames - `df1 (800k rows) and df2 (3 rows).`

If the value of `df1_A` is between `df2_A and df2_B`, the value of `df2_C` should be returned to `df1_C`.

```
for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
         if (row1['df1_A'] >= row2['df2_A']) & (row1['df1_A'] <= row2['df2_B']):
             row1['df1_C'] = row2['df2_C']
```

The easiest and readable way to write this is to use two for loops, but, because it has looped around 2.4 million times, the performance of my program is reduced.  Is there a better way to accomplish my task.

Comment: Show us your looping code.  I can't tell what **the value of df2_C should be returned to df1_C** means when you say they have different lengths.

Comment: Added the code.  This is the logic that I had in with me but perplexed because of the number of loops it has to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so your looping code is, paraphrased:

```
for row1 in df1.rows:
    for row2 in df2.rows:
         if (row1.A >= row2.A) & (row1.A <= row2.B):
             row1.C = row2.C
```

Let's flip the loops:

```
for row2 in df2.rows:
    for row1 in df1.rows:
         if (row1.A >= row2.A) & (row1.A <= row2.B):
             row1.C = row2.C
```

Now, removing the outer loop is not very important because it only runs three times.  Let's vectorize the inner part:

```
for row2 in df2.rows:
    df1.C[(df1.A >= row2.A) & (df1.A <= row2.B)] = row2.C
```

And simplify:

```
for row2 in df2.rows:
    df1.C[df1.A.between(row2.A, row2.B)] = row2.C
```

I hope that's good enough.  Please let us know how much faster this is.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the fact that `df2` contains only three rows!

Consider the following vectorized approach:

**Setup:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10**6, 1)), columns=['val'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 1, 1: 10, 2: 20}, 'B': {0: 5, 1: 13, 2: 20}})
```

**Solution:**

```
qry = ' | '.join(['{0[0]}<=val<={0[1]}'.format(r) for r in df2.values.tolist()])

df1.query(qry)
```

**Timing:** for 1.000.000 rows DF:

```
In [34]: df1.shape
Out[34]: (1000000, 1)

In [35]: %timeit df1.query(qry)
10 loops, best of 3: 46.6 ms per loop
```

**Generated query:**

```
In [36]: qry
Out[36]: '1<=val<=5 | 10<=val<=13 | 20<=val<=20'
```